# How to use padded_batch() in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
X = tf.range(10)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
dataset2 = dataset.repeat(3).padded_batch(7, padded_shapes=([]))
for item in dataset2:
    print(item)
```

output

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 5 6], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([7 8 9 0 1 2 3], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4 5 6 7 8 9 0], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4 5 6 7], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([8 9], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

How to define padded_shapes for getting result like bellow?

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4 5 6], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([7 8 9 0 1 2 3], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4 5 6 7 8 9 0], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4 5 6 7], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([8 9 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Tensorflow dataset api: How to use padded\_batch so that a pads with a specific value without specifying the number of pads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938962/in-tensorflow-dataset-api-how-to-use-padded-batch-so-that-a-pads-with-a-specifi)

Comment: Thanks DHerls for your comments. That is not  a correct answer for my question. Anyway I got an inspiration from the comments you pointed and I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with batch(7).

```
dataset2 = dataset.repeat(3).batch(7).padded_batch(7, padded_shapes=([None]))
```

output

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [7 8 9 0 1 2 3]
 [4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
 [8 9 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(5, 7), dtype=int32)
```